# How to generate file size statistics in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, files, statistics, sizing

Say I have a PC connected to some experimental instrumentation. `C:` is the system partition with Windows 7 and all the programs on it, and `D:` is the storage partition where all the acquired data is saved to. Is there a fast and easy way to generate a rough histogram of the sizes of all files on `D:`? If possible, I'd like to avoid doing tens of searches for different file sizes and generating a histogram by hand. Some simple tool for this would be very handy.

I've found a tool called [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.net), which is nice to visualize all the files, but I couldn't find any feature to get a proper histogram.

Comment: Hi, Nora. Please bring this question to https://superuser.com/ where PC-focused questions are asked and answered. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the following Python script.
Works for me both on Windows and Linux with python 3.8 and matplotlib 3.5.

```python
from pathlib import Path
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def file_size_hist(folder: Path, size_min, size_stop, size_step):

    hist_x = np.logspace(start=np.log2(size_min)/np.log2(size_step),
                         stop=np.log2(size_stop)/np.log2(size_step)+1,
                         num=int(np.log2(size_stop/size_min)/np.log2(size_step))+2,
                         base=size_step,
                         dtype=np.uint64)

    hist_y = np.zeros(hist_x.size, dtype=np.uint64)
    for f in folder.rglob('*'):
        if f.is_file():
            file_size_bytes = f.stat().st_size

            if file_size_bytes < size_min:
                bin = 0
            else:
                bin = np.log2(file_size_bytes//size_min) // np.log2(size_step) + 1
            # Example:
            # file_size_bytes = np.array([0, size_min-1, size_min, size_min+1, size_stop-1, size_stop, size_stop+1])
            # bin             = np.array([0,          0,        1,          1,          22,        23,          23])

            bin = int(np.minimum(bin, hist_y.size-1))   # Last bin includes all files with size >= size_stop
            hist_y[bin] += 1

    return hist_x, hist_y


if __name__ == "__main__":
    size_min_bytes = 2**10     # files with size < size_min_bytes are counted in the first bar
    size_stop_bytes = 2**32    # files with size >= size_stop_bytes are counted in the last bar
    size_step_coeff = 2   # e.g. `[1024, 2048, 4096, ...]` bytes
    target_folder = r"F:"

    hist_x, hist_y = file_size_hist(Path(target_folder), size_min_bytes, size_stop_bytes, size_step_coeff)
    print('Found {} files total'.format(np.sum(hist_y)))
    print('Found {} files with size below 64 KB'.format(np.sum(hist_y * (hist_x < 64*2**10))))

    #
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
    ax.hist(hist_x, weights=hist_y, bins=hist_x, label='file sizes')
    ax.set_xscale('log')
    ax.set_yscale('log')
    ax.set_xlabel('File size in bytes')
    ax.set_ylabel('File count')

    fig.show()

    #   |  bin |  min            |               max |           hist_x               |
    # --+------+-----------------+-------------------+--------------------------------+
    #   |   0  |               0 |              1023 |  1024*2**0                     |
    #   |   1  |  1024*2**0=1024 |              2047 |  1024*2**1                     |
    #   |   2  |  1024*2**1=2048 |              4095 |  1024*2**2                     |
    #   |  22  |  1024*2**21     |     1024*2**22-1  |  1024*2**22 == size_stop_bytes |
    #   |  23  |  1024*2**22     |               inf |  1024*2**23                    |
```

The main benefit is that it is infinitely customizable.
Example result:
[image: Example file size histogram]

Answer (score 0):

SpaceSniffer might be what you want